# Proyecto de Xamarin siempre entra a la directiva NETSTANDARD2_0 en mi librería

Tags: android, xamarin, bluetooth

Estoy escribiendo un plugin Bluetooth LE para Xamarin.

Las plataformas de destino de la librería son netstandard2.0,MonoAndroid9.0 y Xamarin.iOS10.

La librería está siendo referenciada desde el proyecto compartido de Xamarin que es netstandard2.0.

Varias partes del código están segmentadas por directivas de preprocesador validando la plataforma de destino.

Pero al ejecutar desde el proyecto de Android, la ejecución siempre entra a la directiva NETSTANDARD2_0 y no a la otra.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde puede estar el problema?

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.